# Java- "For" Loops condition to end at user input

Tags: loops, random, conditional-statements, user-input

I am a beginner, I am trying to write a code that Loops or generates a random to the amount of times user input specifies. What I currently have is a random that loops to a condition I set to a number just so I don't have infinite outputs. I would like to create a condition that stops at the user's input integer amount. Example, user input how many times they would like to play and the computer randomly outputs only that amount of times. Below is what I have so far. numberOfFlips is my scanner integer of user's input. **How do I get the loop to only run the amount of times of the user input?**

```
    for (numberOfFlips =1; numberOfFlips < 10; numberOfFlips++) {
    
    //Computer generates a pick
     compGuess= rand.nextInt(2);
     
    //Computer generates a pick
     }
        if (compGuess== 0) { 
            System.out.println("Heads");
        } else {System.out.println ("Tails");
```

Comment: You're question isn't particularly clear as to what problem you are having. If you are receiving a value from the user as to how many times to execute the `for` loop, it will exit the loop once that value is reached. Every time the loop runs it increases the iterator value by 1 so once it gets to the user entered value it will stop executing. Your `for` loop would look like `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)` - declare a new integer in the for loop to keep track of how many time thes loop has ran and it will terminate once it reaches the user entered value.

Comment: How do I get the loop to only run the amount of times of the user input?

Comment: I showed you in the above comment. A `for` loop will execute as many times as the user input by increasing the count by 1 on each iteration of the loop. So if `numberOfFlips = 10`, then this `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++){}` will run 10 times. I think you may need to read more about a `for loop` - (https://www.javatpoint.com/java-for-loop)